# Any way of mapping the wordpress installation to the website root?

Tags: wordpress

I installed Wordpress on a cPanel account, and it's accessible by visiting `website.com/wordpress`. What would I need to do to make it so that when a user visits `website.com` , he actually sees the `website.com/wordpress` ? I think there is a better solution than adding a redirect inside an `index.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .htaccess to make the wordpress location as your Directory index using a .htaccess file in your root above wordpress folder..

and include following in that .htaccess file

DirectoryIndex wordpress/index

Comment: if you can install wordpress in root folder.. you can do like that too as said by Andre.

Comment: Thank you! However, it only worked after I changed `wordpress/index` to `wordpress/index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Though I do not know about the cPanel admin section - look into your domain configuration or general settings: There should be a place where you can set the the target of the domain or your 'home directory'. it currently should point to the root directory '/'.

Simply let it point to the '/wordpress' folder and you should be fine. If you do not have access to the domain config, install the wordpress directly into the root directory.